# Use Nodejs and grunt to build static html files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bash, gruntjs

For the past few years, I've been using PHP and bash scripting to generate static HTML files for clients who can only support static html on their servers. The process is, I create a giant array consisting of all the data / image urls for the site. I use bash to run the PHP script that snapshots all the rendered pages and makes them static html files. I've just starting using grunt and noticed that its very similar to what I do with bash and PHP. Is there a node equivalent to what I am doing with bash and PHP that will let me generate static html files from a json array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of great NodeJS static site generators. The top 3 are probably:

- http://wintersmith.io/
- http://docpad.org/
- https://github.com/flatiron/blacksmith

Comment: Thank you wintersmith.io seems to be the one